# Mysql workbenck can't start in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, workbench, ubuntu-13.04

I have recently installed lamp on my ubuntu 13.04. I also installed mysql workbench 32bit. First time i tried workbench it worked perfectly. Then I closed it and when i tried to open it, it just showed me the logo of workbench and then it was closed. I think I have to delete a file of workbench, but I can't find anything. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I solved it.I just deleted the file " wb_options.xml ".

```
~/.mysql/workbench//wb_options.xml
```

Now it works fine.